# Checking whether a word is TCL keyword or Not

Tags: tcl, operator-keyword, keyword, keyword-search

The question is regarding TCL. I have a word I want to compare whether it is TCL keyword or not. Please suggest me is there any way to do that?

1. I was thinking may create a list which contains all TCL keywords then compare with the word I'm having. any suggestion on creating that list?

Is there any better method?

Regards
keerthan

Comment: The info commands and info vars commands yield lists of names that are currently in use and have meaning in the program, but note that they are not keywords in the sense used in other languages, nor are they reserved words.

Comment: one clarification : what u mean by **not keywords in the sense used in other languages, nor are they reserved words**

Comment: They don't have a specified meaning hard-coded into the interpreter, and you are allowed to assign a new meaning to them.

Answer (score 3):

Tcl doesn't have keywords. The language design explicitly doesn't use them.

But you do have a standard set of commands (as listed in the index of the manual pages at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/contents.htm; only a few of those don't correspond to actual commands). You can then add a few extra words (`then`, `else`, `elseif`) and that will give you a sensible first cut at things that you can pretend are keywords for the purposes of stuff like syntax highlighting.

If you're doing actual parsing of Tcl, you need [a different approach](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1660).